# Typesetting the "spectral voltage noise density" unit "volt/sqrt(hertz)" with siunix

Tags: siunitx

How do I typeset the "*spectral voltage noise density*" unit "*volt/sqrt(hertz)*" with **siunitx**?

My naive (and unsuccessful) approach was:

```
\SI{100}[per-mode=symbol]{\nano\volt\per\sqrt{\hertz}}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[`siunitx`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/siunitx) sets units in text mode, so you have to ensure to be in math mode (thanks egreg and Joseph) for the root and then switch back to text for the unit. Not that complicated if you define a new unit and use it afterwards.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\DeclareSIUnit{\sqrthz}{\ensuremath{\sqrt{\text{\hertz}}}}
\DeclareSIUnit{\voltnoise}{\volt\per\sqrthz}
\begin{document}
\SI[per-mode=symbol]{100}{\nano\voltnoise}
\[ \SI{3.5}{\mega\voltnoise} \sqrt{7} \]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Of course, if you always want to have the fraction as the symbol, you can add the optional argument to the declaration.

Comment: As of today (03.02.2018) one can use `\sqrt` in `siunitx` in text without further stuff, unless one uses the option `detect-mode` (or `detect-all` of course). Then the above seems to be a good workaround.

Comment: In `siunitx` v3 this does not work (`\hertz` undefined). I use `\DeclareSIUnit{\sqrthz}{\ensuremath{\sqrt\mathrm{Hz}}}`, but probably there is a smarter way.

Comment: @Rmano you could as well define `\hertz` beforehand and use it then as done above.

Comment: @Skillmon `\hertz` is defined, the problem is that it is not "seen" inside the `\sqrt` (sorry, I expressed myself badly)

Comment: @Rmano `\sqrt{\unit{\hertz}}` (also, in your comment above the braces after the `\sqrt` are missing, it should be `\sqrt{\mathrm{Hz}}`).

Comment: @Skillmon yes, you're right!