# siunitx - How can I typeset (-1/2)?

Tags: siunitx, units

I'm trying to typeset the unit Å^(-1) eV^(-½) with `siunitx`, using `\sisetup{locale=DE}` (I don't think this makes any difference here).

Thanks to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/218948/85790), I have been able to figure out how to typeset roots, but this

```
\si{\per\angstrom\per\ensuremath{\sqrt{\text{\electronvolt}}}}
```

doesn't give me the desired result. (Neither does

```
\si[per-mode=fraction]{\per\angstrom\per\ensuremath{\sqrt{\text{\electronvolt}}}}
```

As a matter of fact, both lines yield exactly the same output.)

My theory is that the `\ensuremath` somehow overwrites the rules for 
`\per`.

Is there a more elegant way than

```
\si{\angstrom^{-1}\electronvolt^{-1/2}
```

to achieve the exponential expression of this unit?

Any help and/or comments are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The moment you use anything that's not strictly a unit macro, `siunitx` uses 'literal' mode so just typesets your input. You seem to want

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\begin{document}
\si{\per\angstrom\per\electronvolt\tothe{1/2}}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Wow, that's exactly what I needed. Didn't know about that command.